# Как сравнить 2 строки с учетом равенства указнных символов?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Изучаю регулярные выражения.

Есть 4 строки, например:

```
s1 = "stroka1_hello"
s2 = "stroka1 hello"
s3 = "stroka1  hello"
s4 = "stroka1__hello_"
```

Строки s1 и s2 отличаются только " " и "_" и нужно определить, что они равны.

Строки s3 и s4 тоже были бы равны, но в конце s4 есть "_" и они не равны.

Можно ли с помощью регулярных выражений проверить проверить строки на равенства с учетом того, что " " равен "_"? Подскажите как, какие шаблоны использовать?

Comment: а зачем регулярные выражения ? просто замените все _ на пробелы и сравните.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IsEquals(string s1, string s2) {
  var s11 = s1.Replace("_"," ");
  return s11.Equals(s2);
}
```

Comment: И как сам не догадался))))